# PHP Simplify a ternary operation

Tags: php, ternary-operator

In PHP, is there a way to simplify this even more, without using an `if()`?

```
$foo = $bar!==0 ? $foo : '';
```

I was wondering if there was a way to not reassign `$foo` to itself if the condition is satisfied. I understand there is a way to do this in Javascript (using &&, right?), but was wondering if there was a way to do this in PHP.

Comment: Why would you want to simply this even further? Do you want the poor guy who's going to be maintaining your code search the manual every time he comes across something like this? I wouldn't.

Comment: voted up, good point Jan

Comment: Also an upvote for that comment, @Jan. `if ($bar == 0) $foo = '';` is just as simple as the ternary, doesn't involve self-assignment, and is actually more readable.

Comment: Disagreed; ternary operators are easily read. The example given by paxdiablo doesn't do the same as the ternary operator above; if $bar doesn't equal 0, then nothing is assigned to $foo and it will be an undefined variable further on.  To do the same you need to have an else clause in there and assign something else - much longer, much less readable.

Comment: @El Look at the question again, if `$bar` is not `0`, `$foo` is assigned the value of `$foo` (i.e. left untouched), so the variable must already exist.

Comment: @deceze - True.  I generally use it to ensure that a variable has a suitable default, e.g. $f = isset($f) ?: 0;, which is more succinct.  I still disagree about the readability, but I guess that's up to personal taste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, you can use the logical and (`&&`) operator in PHP as well.

```
$bar === 0 && $foo = '';
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation/tutorials on this method? I've seen it used but never fully understood it.

Comment: @Kerry It's the same as in `if ($foo && $bar)`. Instead of just variables or values you can put whole expressions in there as well, like `if ($foo == 0 && $bar = 'baz')`. But it doesn't have to be used just in `if ()` expressions. `&&` is a short-circuit operator, meaning it won't evaluate the second half if the first half is `false`. So `$foo = ''` will only be looked at and hence executed if `$bar === 0`.

Answer (score 10):

In PHP 5.3 the short form of the ternary operator has finally arrived, so you can do the following.

```
$foo = $bar ?: '';
```

See [the Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) section - "Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise."

Comment: The code doesn't do what op asked for, and I don't see a way to leverage short ternary operator here.