# Alternate of if(isset) then this else this

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, default-value

I Have to do

```
if(isset($someval))
    $var = $someval
else 
    $var = $defaultVal
```

repeatedly for lots of variables at different times. Is there some better alternate to this?

something like

```
$var = $someval||$defaultVal
```

Having said that I already know about ternary operator.

Comment: Wait for PHP 7 with `??`

Comment: Okay, Does it means currently there is no solution to this.

Comment: Can I ask Why this question is down voted

Comment: @Arpita didn't do that, but it might be that there are some similar questions around SO.

Comment: @AlanMachado Then mark it as a duplicate instead of downvoting

Comment: @AlanMachado I meant it should have been marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Using ternary operators (? and :) you can do something like this:

```
$var = isset($someval) ? $someval : $defaultVal;
```

See http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples for more examples

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

`$var = ($someval) ? $someval : $defaultVal;`

`isset` is redundant to boolean checking, you don't have to use if you want shorter lines.

**EDIT**: since OP stated through question editing, after the answers were published, that it *already has knowledge of ternary operations*, there are even other [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034338/php-simplify-a-ternary-operation) to consider:

- Assigning itself if `TRUE` allows to ommit the first clause:

  `$var = $someval ?: $defaultVal;`
- Using pure logical expression:

  `$someval && $var = $defaultVal;`

Comment: you don't even need the brackets

Comment: @san.chez sure not BUT, as I have a historic with [*operation precedence*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781683/why-is-ternary-operator-ignoring-condition-order), I adopt it as good practice (doesn't hurt, doesn't affect readability and makes good habit when it comes to be useful)